# How to convert 3-dimensional array of fixed size to a reference-style?

Tags: rust, pass-by-reference, array-algorithms

I work with 3-dimensional arrays of fixed size. For the first time I used passing by value.

```
fn some_func(matrix: [[[f64;Z];Y];X]) {// body}

fn main() {
    let m = [[[0.0;Z];Y];X];
    some_func(m);
}
```

It means copying all elements and is bad for efficiency. So I decided to remake code by using references.

If I do it like this:

```
fn some_func(matrix: &[[[f64;Z];Y];X]) {// body}

fn main() {
    let m = [[[0.0;Z];Y];X];
    some_func(&m);
}
```

it won't copy variable "matrix", but will still copy matrix[i]. To avoid copying, as I understand, &[&[&[f64]]] type of function argument should be used. But... How can I convert `[[[f64;Z];Y];X]` to `&[&[&[f64]]]` to match the function signature with the argument being passed?

Or the only way is to use reference-notation while initialization, and even store the array as a reference to array of references (it is a field of a structure, in fact)?

Comment: *t won't copy variable "matrix", but will still copy matrix[i].*, how so?

Comment: Where and why do you think matrix[i] would be copied in the second version?
It makes it sound like the reference would need to point to a copy of the whole 3D-Array for that to make sense, which would make it the same as the first version in terms of copying the whole array, but now you only have a reference to the copy rather than the copy itself.
Maybe looking at the size of the parameter types helps? Here is a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9aa2ec5433a06e1d1514c7c89d3d3dd5) where the sizes are printed.

Comment: maybe i messed up...

so, you mean, that using func(&arr) is enough to prevent copying a lot of data (about 10^6 numbers)?

Answer (score 1):

They are not copied. Just having a reference `&` to the outer one should be enough:

```rust
fn printer(l: &[[usize; 1]; 1]) {
    println!("{}", &(l[0]) as *const _ as usize);
}

fn main() {
    let l = [[1]];
    println!("{}", &(l[0]) as *const _ as usize);
    printer(&l);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b2490db65171b3b1679d5a8c73e7e13)

Outputs:

```
140725001518400
140725001518400
```

It means that it doesn't matter if you access from the original one or the `&`, you get access to the same inner structures.

Comment: Ah... Now i see. The question was stupid. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Netwave pro tip: you can use the pointer format specifier `{:p}` and avoid all that casting: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=077fec1868de6f8d12a2df555d815ed6)

Comment: @kmdreko, nice. Since it is not something I use everyday is the kind of stuff I forget all the time :D, thanks!